# Azure Maps - Search local geojson file

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I can get local geojson data and can pin on AzureMaps. But how can I search and pin selected place in maps?

I couldn't find resource.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would loop through your data, apply your custom filter logic. You could then either do:

- Copy the selected items into an array, then update the data source to only contain those.
- Add a custom property to indicate selected state, then use a style expression on your layer to change how they look or use the filter option to limit what's displayed.

Here are a couple related examples:

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Select%20data%20in%20drawn%20polygon%20area

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Filter%20Symbols%20by%20Property

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Filter%20Data%20Along%20Route

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Select%20shapes%20with%20selection%20control

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Selection%20control